# Convert @Ajax.ActionLink to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am in the process of learning MVC3 and I have the following `@Ajax.Actionlink` in a partial view that I would like to convert to use the jQuery method of an ajax call, however I have two main problems that I can't quite figure out:

- How to get the parameters into to ajax call. (The userID is fine as it is in the ViewModel of the partial view, but I can't see how to get the customerID from the instance of the child collection.)
- How to return the partial view into the specified div. (When I try this it just redirects to the partial view, whereas the current `@Ajax.ActionLink` does correctly update the div.)

Below is all of (I think) the relevant code:

**The Partial View**

```
@model ..snip../CustomerViewModel

<div id="updatedablediv">
<table class="customers" style="width: 50%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th> 
            <th>
                Actions
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>      
    <tbody>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (Customer item in Model.Customers)
        { 
            <tr id="customer-id-@item.CustomerID">
                @Html.HiddenFor(i => item.CustomerID)
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(i => item.Name)
                </td>  
                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCustomer", "MyController", new { userID = Model.UserID, customerID = item.CustomerID },
                        new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updatedablediv", HttpMethod = "Get" }, new { @class = "standardbutton" })
                </td>       
            </tr>
            }
        }       
        </tbody>     
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult DeleteCustomer(int userID, int customerID)
{
    try
    {
        //Delete code
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes.");
    }

    CustomerViewModel returnViewModel = new CustomerViewModel()
    {
        UserID = userID,
        Customers = repository.Customers
    };

    return PartialView("CustomerPartial", returnViewModel);
}
```

I have tried doing this, but I keep getting into trouble with the issues mentioned above. One of my tries was with the following jQuery:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){  
    var loadUrl = $('#buttonid').attr('href');
    $("#updatedablediv")  
        .html(DeleteCustomer)  
        .load(loadUrl, {userID: @model.UserID);  
});
```

Any pointers to help me convert this `@Ajax.ActionLink` into jQuery would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much,

**UPDATE HTML**

This is the html of an instance of a `<tr>` in my partial view.

```
<tr id="customer-id-1003">
    <input id="item_CustomerID" name="item.CustomerID" type="hidden" value="1003" />
    <td>
        James
    </td>  
    <td>
        <a class="standardbutton" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#updatedablediv" href="/MyController/DeleteCustomer?userID=12&amp;customerID=1003">Delete</a>
    </td>       
</tr>
```

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you posted the HTML code as it ends up in the browser. This would allow anyone not familiar with ASP.NET to answer your question properly.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and posted a part of the HTML, hopefully that is the part that is required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes of the generated link give you everything you need to properly perform the AJAX request:

```html
<a class="standardbutton"
   data-ajax="true"
   data-ajax-method="Get"
   data-ajax-mode="replace"
   data-ajax-update="#updatedablediv"
   href="/MyController/DeleteCustomer?userID=12&amp;customerID=1003"
>
```

So let's do this:

```js
$('.standardbutton[data-ajax="true"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        method: $this.data('ajaxMethod').toUpperCase(),
        cache: false,
        url: $this.attr('href'),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(resp) {
            // this assumes that the data-ajax-mode is always "replace":
            $($this.data('ajaxUpdate')).html(resp);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I forgot to add the preventDefault, that bit of jQuery was from memory! The problem still remains that I don't know how to pass in the second parameter from the model's child object. Thanks.